# Gender of BEAS-2B cell culture

Tags: cell-culture

I recognize some interesting patterns when analysing DNA methylation of BEAS-2B cells. Does anybody know, if the cell culture is female or male? I already asked the customer support of Sigma Aldrich without success.

Information on the official website just mention "non-cancerous individuals" as source organisms.

http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/95102433?lang=de&region=DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell line is most likely genetically male. On the English (US) site, the **Description** box has several sections, of which one is *DNA Profile*. In there, it lists [amelogenin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelogenin) as `X, Y`. This gene is located on both the X and Y chromosomes (AMELX and AMELY, respectively), which have distinct PCR-detectable sequence differences. It is often used in *helping* to determine the gender of unknown samples in the realm of forensics - it is not 100% accurate, so other genetic tests (such as for [SRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRY)) are also performed.

Comment: My DNA methylation data don't show a clear male oder female status. There is definitly an observable "male" effect, but a clear classification is not possible with my dataset. The results indicate a mixture. Anyway, I will remove gonosomal probes from further analyses. Thanks for your answer!